# libiconv.dylib not found in Xcode 7 GM

Tags: ios9, xcode7

libiconv.dylib is missing in Xcode 7 GM, But found in Xcode 6.4 release
My OS version: OS X El Capitan GM

[image]

Answer (score 22):

Oh, you are fast.

Since Xcode 7 and iOS 9, Apple did a lot to strip the size of apps, including changing `.dylib` to `.tbd`.

To solve your problem, you don't need to add library & framework. Instead, you can add the library by changing the following option:

> Other Linker Flags > Add "-l{yourlibraryname} (no space after `-l`)

In your case, you can add `-liconv` in `Other Linker Flags`.

For those who are curious, the `.tbd` files are new "text-based stub libraries", that provide a much more compact version of the stub libraries for use in the SDK, and help significantly reduce its download size.

Reference: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/8609#8609